# Using ARMAIRF in matlab

Tags: matlab, impulse-response

Using Matlab's `[beta,Sigma,E,CovB,logL] = mvregress` function, I have conducted an OLS for two models:

```
Y1t = intercept+B1(Y1t-1)+B2(Y2t-1)+B3(Y1t-2)+B4(Y2t-2)
Y2t = intercept+B1(Y1t-1)+B2(Y2t-1)+B3(Y1t-2)+B4(Y2t-2)
```

The beta coefficients are given in a 5X2 array where each column has coefficients of a particular model and each row has coefficients of a particular explanatory variable.

I have been asked to generate impulse response plots using the `armairf` function. Can someone help me out how it can be done?